# How do I randomize a signed multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, random, system-verilog

I have declared a signed multidimensional array as follows:

```sv
typedef logic signed [3:0][31:0] hires_frame_t;
typedef hires_frame_t [3:0] hires_capture_t;
hires_capture_t rndpacket;
```

I want to randomize this array such that each element has a value between -32768 to 32767, in 32-bit two's-complement.

I've tried the following:

```systemverilog
assert(std::randomize(rndpacket) with
     {foreach (rndpacket[channel])
       foreach (rndpacket[channel][subsample])
          {rndpacket[channel][subsample] < signed'(32768);
           rndpacket[channel][subsample] >= signed'(-32768);}});
```

This compiles well, but (mentor graphics) modelsim fails in simulation claiming

```
randomize() failed due to conflicts between the following constraints:
#   clscummulativedata.sv(56): (rndpacket[3][3] < 32768);
#   cummulativedata.sv(57): (rndpacket[3][3] >= 32'hffff8000);
```

This is clearly something linked to usage of signed vectors. I had a feeling that everything should be fine as array is declared as `signed` as well as thresholds in the `randomize` call, but apparently not. If I replace the range by 0-65535, everything works as expected.

What is the correct way to randomize such a signed array?

Comment: `32'hffff8000` is unsigned; `32'shffff8000` is signed. You need the signed one.

Comment: @Serge `32'hffff8000` was output from the tool. It is treating the RHS as unsigned because the LHS is unsigned. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `hires_frame_t` is a signed 128-bit 2-dimensional *packed* array, and selecting a part of a packed array is *unsigned*. A way of keeping the part-select of a packed dimension signed is using a separate `typedef` for the dimension you want signed:

```
typedef bit signed [31:0] int32_t;
typedef int32_t [3:0] hires_frame_t;
typedef hires_frame_t [3:0] hires_capture_t;
```

Another option is putting the `signed` cast on the LHS of the comparisons. Your signed cast on the RHS is not doing anything because bare decimal numbers are already treated as signed. A comparison is unsigned if one or both sides are unsigned.

```
 assert(std::randomize(rndpacket) with {
       foreach (rndpacket[channel,subsample])
          {signed'(rndpacket[channel][subsample]) < 32768;
           signed'(rndpacket[channel][subsample]) >= -32768;}});
```

BTW, I'm showing the LRM compliant way of using a 2-d `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (bit surprising for me). Does that mean that using the original declaration I get unsigned any time I do: rndpacket[0] and rndpacket[0][0]? Or I just get unsigned when selecting rndpacket[0]?

Comment: The only selected part in your original code that is _signed_ is `rndpacket[i]`. `rndpacket`,`rndpacket[i][j]`, and `rndpacket[i][j][k]` are all _unsigned_.